# node.js authenticate user before sending html page

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, auth0

I want to authenticate a user before they access a few .html pages that should only be seen when logged in. Right now I have been making a GET request to my backend to complete this, but the process takes a little bit of time and the webpage does end up loading and flashes its content for about a half second before the server realizes its a non-authenticated user and starts redirecting. is there a more secure/better way to handle this?

i am using auth0 for now if that makes any difference

I have successfully implemented a middleware that protects all endpoints like so:

```
app.get('/test', secured(), function(req, res){ ...
```

but i need to authenticate a user before displaying a few html pages, which i have been doing on the client side. The webpage that is supposed to be protected still flashes for about a second before the get request on the client side redirects it to the login page.

i am using auth0 if that helps.

**TL;DR**: how do i authenticate user is logged in before serving a webpage in express?

Comment: You claim you have successfully implemented a middleware that protects all the routes, so what exactly is not working? It should be as simple as responding to the request in the "secured" middleware instead of calling `next()`. I think it would be helpful if you posted your middleware implementation.

Comment: Jake you are right, but i'm curious as to how i should go about using this secured() middleware before the html page is served to the client

Comment: I'm assuming this is a problem because you are serving the HTML page using `express.static`?

Comment: It sounds like your content is already on the front end before the user is authenticated, meaning it could be inspected by the user regardless if they are logged in or not. Can you tell us a little bit about your framework? Did you follow an auth0 quickstart?